# A couple of simple questions about infinite groups

Tags: group-theory

I need to find infinite groups, who are (if exist):
 1. Except the identity, every element of the group is from order 2.
 2. Except the identity, every element of the group is from order 3.

For the first I wanted to take: $$G=\{k\in Z|cis(\pi k)=+-1\}$$ 
But I don't sure about the opposite. For the second didn't had any ideas.

How do I generate such groups in generally?

Comment: Hint: Think about $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Another hint: your job becomes easier if you can ensure your infinite groups are abelian. Then products of order-2 elements automatically have order 2.

Comment: Rather, if every element has order $\le 2$ then the group is abelian.

Comment: Your $G = \mathbb Z$ so definitely no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think about $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$.

Try to figure it out before mousing over the following:

> $(\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z)^\omega $ and $(\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z)^\omega$

Comment: But isn't the order of that quotient groups is finite ? Is 2 and 3? 
Isn't that quotient groups are isomorphic to $Z_2$ and $Z_3$, which are finite? 
I thought about it in the first place, but they seemed to me to be finite.